# org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat7

I have following code in my servlet

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("Getting Context scoped attributes<br>");
ServletContext sc = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
Enumeration contextAttribNames = sc.getAttributeNames();
while(contextAttribNames.hasMoreElements()){
  String attribName = (String) contextAttribNames.nextElement();
  String attribValue = (String) sc.getAttribute(attribName);//Line#21
  out.println("<b>" + attribName + ":</b> " + attribValue + "<br>");
}
```

It just tries to get all the attributes associated with application/context scope and print their values.

The code compiles fine, but fails when I invoke this servlet from an url pattern

Following is the error I get

"HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    com.servlet.scopes.GetContextScopeServlet.doGet(GetContextScopeServlet.java:21)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

As per the documentation, javax.servlet.ServletContext has a method to get attribute with following signature
public Object getAttribute(String attribName)

and this is the reason why I'm casting to String at Line#21

Please help me in understanding the problem and resolving the issue...

Env Details :
OS - Windows7
Server - Apache Tomcat 7.x
JavaEE-6 specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are not necessarily all of type `String`. They can be any object type. But you're trying to use them all as `String` objects

```
String attribValue = (String) sc.getAttribute(attribName);//Line#21
```

You don't know their type, so you can just do

```
Object attribValue = sc.getAttribute(attribName);//Line#21
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes in a `ServletContext` aren't always `String` objects; they can be anything, and are often such items as database pools. You should almost never cast an object to `String`; instead, properly parameterize your `Enumeration` as `Enumeration<String>`, and either use `toString()` on the attribute values or just use the bare `Object` in your string concatenation to have the compiler call `toString()` implicitly.